# Set Button half the window size in .NET Maui

Tags: maui

I'd like to set the size of a button in .NET Maui to take up half of the window size, or some other fraction.  I want to have some big buttons, and I can not lie.  If I was doing this in html/css, I would set the width to 50%.  In .NET Maui, I would think that I would set the widthrequest to 50%.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do that because .WidthRequest only takes a double.  So, I thought I would get the width of the current window.  I try

```
var width = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
```

That only seems to return a zero when I try this in windows in debug mode.  Googling doesn't seem to be much help.  Is there a way to set a button to a width?

TIA

Comment: **where** are you doing this?  If you try to get the width before the layout has been calculated it won't have a value

Comment: @Jason - I first tried this after the InitializeComponent() method in the class initialization.  I also tried this in the OnAppearing() override.  Neither worked.  Where should I put it?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT  I always have questions.  :-)  I think I am set for the moment.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Maui has proportional sizing for grid row and columns. You don't explain where you want your button but you can use multiples of * proportional.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

If you put a button in that middle row then it will be half the width of the grid and central.

Similarly, define 3 columns with * widths and you have a central cell half the width and half the height of the grid.

Comment: Thanks @Andy.  I think my ultimate problem here is that I forgot about the vertical and horizontal option properties on the visual objects.  Once I put that in with the grid, I think that this will get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I test the code and it work well:

```
<Button                
   x:Name="btn"                
   Text="btn"/>

double width= DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width/4;    
public MainPage()
{        
   InitializeComponent();        
   btn.WidthRequest=width; 
}
```

Comment: Won't this make the button half the screen size rather than half the window size?